# Getting proportion of each of one variable that is True for another in 'pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in `pandas` that includes a column 'A' and a boolean-valued column 'B' and would like to find the values of 'A' for which at least a certain number, n, of the rows have True for 'B'.

The closest thing I can com up with is to

```
df.query('B == True')['A'].value_counts()
```

and then look at the numbers to see which ones are greater than, n.

Is there a more pythonic (or more ailuropodian) way of doing this (perhaps even an approach they returns only those with a count greater than n, or the proportions that are True)?

Comment: Aside: I'm campaigning for "pandorable".

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to a filter:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, True], [1, True], [2, False], [2, True]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: g = df.groupby('A')

In [13]: g.filter(lambda x: x['B'].sum() > 1)
Out[13]: 
   A     B
0  1  True
1  1  True
```

To find just the values of A where this is True you could use the sum agg method:

```
In [21]: res = g.B.sum() > 1

In [22]: res[res]
Out[22]: 
A
1    True
Name: B, dtype: bool

In [23]: res[res].index
Out[23]: Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```